# How to say "This day is going by too quickly" in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, usage

It's daylight savings time day (Spring equinox) and we all lost an hour. How would I casually express that this day is going by too quickly?

Something like:

この日の時間は早すぎています。

Comment: I'm afraid but 「日が経つのが早い」 means "Day**s** go by quickly" rather than "**One** day goes by quickly." 「[日]{ひ}が短い」 means "daytime is short / the sun sets early / it gets dark soon". You'd say 「(今日は)[一日]{いちにち}が短い」「(今日は)時間が経つのが速い」 for "The day is short / Time goes by quickly (today)."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We usually say ”日が短い” or "日が経{た}つのが早い"、and add "です" or "ですね" in conversation. You may also add "この頃{ごろ}は - these days" to before "”日が短い” and "日が経{た}つのが早い."

Though ”日が短い” refers to phisical shortness of the length of a day, and "日が経{た}つのが早い" rather connotes your feeling of the quick passage of time, both phrases are often used in the greeting in our conversation.

この日の時間は早すぎています sounds awkward and illogical because a day can't be short only on a single day around this time of the year.

Comment: Thanks! One could argue that today is indeed the one day around this time of year that is shorter, as we only have 23 hours today.

Answer (score 2):

We commonly say もうこんな時間だ (だ can be replaced with か or omitted) which roughly translates to "Alas, it's already [unspecified] o'clock!"

It might be a bit strange to say it when you have no means to check the time.

Why not

> もう夕方だ
>   It's already evening.